# Get parameters and store and use them on variables to use on my method

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-resource

I want to get some parameters and use them to reset password function from firebase.

This is how my link looks like: 
http://localhost:8080/passwordreset?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=y6FIOAtRUKYf88Rt5OlEwxUuTyEmb3M4gquZSIseX2UAAAFevpj-gw&apiKey=AIzaSyBaCCvq-ZEfQmdrL7fmElXDjZF_J-tku2I

I want to get `mode`, `oobCode` and `apiKey`.
Here is what I have for now:

```
export default {


data: function() {
    return {
        passwordNew: '',
        passwordConfirm: '',
        mode:'',
        actionCode: '',
        continueUrl: '',
    }
},
methods: {
    handleResetPassword: function() {
        var accountEmail;

        firebase.auth().verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {
            var accountEmail = email;
            firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(this.actionCode, this.passwordNew).then(function(resp) {

                alert("Password reset success");
                this.$router.push('hello')
            }).catch(function(error) {
                // Error occurred during confirmation. The code might have expired or the
                // password is too weak.
                console.log("error 1")
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Invalid or expired action code. Ask user to try to reset the password
            // again.
            console.log("error 2")
        });
    },
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thank you @Bert for your help, but i don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: It is at least partly, non of the code above will work. You can't access your data properties because you are using a `function(){}` in your `then` callbacks. You should use an arrow function, a closure, or bind.

Comment: My main question is how to get  `mode`, `oobCode` and `apiKey` with vue-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Firebase documentation:

> Some user management actions, such as updating a user's email address
>   and resetting a user's password, result in emails being sent to the
>   user. These emails contain links that recipients can open to complete
>   or cancel the user management action. By default, user management
>   emails link to the default action handler, which is a web page hosted
>   at a URL in your project's Firebase Hosting domain.

link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

You need to get those parameters and store them on variables, from firebase documentation i got those snippets and just wrote the `getParameterByName` function:

```
function getParameterByName( name ){
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
    // Get the action to complete.
    var mode = getParameterByName('mode');
    // Get the one-time code from the query parameter.
    var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode');
    // (Optional) Get the continue URL from the query parameter if available.
    var continueUrl = getParameterByName('continueUrl');
```

You need to get those parameters first and verify the actioncode on the verifyPasswordResetCode method, then you can change the password and store it along with the action code to the method.

In your export default :

```
data: function() {
        return {
            passwordNew: '',
            passwordConfirm: '',
            mode: mode,
            actionCode: actionCode,
            continueUrl: continueUrl,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleResetPassword: function() {
            var passwordNew = this.passwordNew
            var actionCode = this.actionCode
            firebase.auth().verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {
                console.log("ActionCode: "+ actionCode);

                firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, passwordNew).then(function(resp) {

                    alert("Password reset success");
                    this.$router.push('hello')
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("error 1"+ error)
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Action code is invalid"+ error)
            });

        },
    }
```